# Show bootstrap alert on specific referrer ref=example

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter-bootstrap, url, referrer

I'm trying to show a normal alert (standard from bootstrap) if I get a visitor from a specific referrer. I have my alert

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<strong>Bold</strong> This is some text
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
```

and I have this as a trigger

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?example\.com\/\?ref=example(\/|$)/i)) {
('.alert').alert();
}
```

This is not working unfortunately and I am not a regex expert, so I don't really know where I'm going wrong here. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the `ref` string?

Comment: that would be example.com/?ref=example (example.com would be my landing-page and `example` is the referrer)

Comment: No `https://` at the start? Then, remove it from the regex. Otherwise, the [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/58P5TE/1).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `?` cannot appear in the protocol or domain you could simple use this:

```
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/\?ref=example\b/)) {
    ('.alert').alert();
}
```

The `\b` at the end covers the case where you might have additional parameters. In case the ref parameter is not the first you could use this: `/[\&\?]ref=example\b/`

If you want to test for domain name as well use this regex:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]*?\bexample.com\/\?ref=example\b/
```